# For each loop into URLFetchapp

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am trying to loop through a sheet to complete the same API call but with different rows of data. I can feel I am getting close so any help would be awesome.

```
function postAnnoucement() {
    //function info () {
    var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
    rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
                if (index !== 0) {
                    var data = {
                        'account_notification[subject]': "Test3",
                        'account_notification[message]': "Test3",
                        'account_notification[start_at]': row[2],//date
                        'account_notification[end_at]': row[3],///date
                        "account_notification[icon]": 'warning',
                        "account_notification_roles[]": 'Admin'
                    };
                    var options = {
                        'method': "post",
                        'headers': {
                            "Authorization": 'Bearer xyz '
                        },
                        'payload': data
                    };
                    UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[1], options); //row 1 is my url
        }
  }
);
}
```

Comment: Please add more details including some sample data and if your script throws an error add it textually.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?